# can I Re- encryp my wallet with a wallet.dat file from before encryption

Tags: encryption

My computer crashed and I lost access to my bitcoin wallet.. before that happened I knew I had lost my passphrase so when trying to recover my wallet with my wallet.dat I looked for a very early dated wallet.dat and loaded that, when it came up it was not encrypted so I encrypted it.

and made a new passphrase should that bring my wallet back with all the coins with the new encryption

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not bring back any of your coins. The encryption process regenerates all of the private keys in your wallet. Furthermore, the private keys generated are not based on your password in anyway; they are random. So re-encrypting an unencrypted backup will not let you get access to your lost Bitcoin.

Comment: thank you for the quick and concise response it is not what I wanted to hear but what i thought was a good possibility you already get a vote a solid answer with which to work from is rare for newbs like me I would like to ask you're advice for my situation Has what I have done eliminated any chance of getting back my wallet still encrypted with the original Pass word

Comment: as part of my next step I have all the recent wallet .dat files and 2 hard drives with only win 7 and bitcoin -qt v 15.1 fully loaded and synchronized

Comment: I forgot to add the computer or bitcoin crashed when reloading that re encrypted old wallet. I was never able get that drive to boot again. Thats why the new hard drives  loaded. I want to try  to rescan that wallet.dat file.  I will wait till tomorrow to see if you respond  I have made so may mistake  at this point i would be a bigger fool not to wait

Comment: Its to great to have a site like this so sad it took me so long to find it thanks again

Comment: Find your most recent backup of your wallet and import it into Bitcoin Core by putting it in the Bitcoin Core datadir. If it is recent enough, you should see your coins when you start Core.